# Cocoa-Touch – Guidelines on what thread to perform GUI updates

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa-touch, user-interface, grand-central-dispatch

I know as a general guideline you should always perform GUI updates on the main thread. But sometimes it's not that obvious. E.g where should I perform the calls:

`setBadgeValue:` of a `UITabBarItem`?

Or

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES]`

In the class reference it's not specified whether these methods can be run on a non-main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rule is that you should keep UIKit updates to the main thread, unless UIKit calls through your implementation from another thread.

> **Reference**: [Important: The UIKit classes are generally not thread safe. All drawing-related operations should be performed on your application’s main thread.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/graphicsdrawingoverview/graphicsdrawingoverview.html)

[From iOS 4 release notes:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iPhoneOS4.html)

- Drawing to a graphics context in UIKit is now thread-safe. Specifically:
  The routines used to access and manipulate the graphics context can now correctly handle contexts residing on different threads.
- String and image drawing is now thread-safe.
- Using color and font objects in multiple threads is now safe to do.

With that information, and unless I or somebody else digs up more docs (which I scanned release notes and saw no more):

> `setBadgeValue:` of a UITabBarItem?

Assume it is safe to call only from the main thread.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES]
```

Assume it is safe to call only from the main thread.

Comment: Thanks Justin, though in the release notes I can not see any information regarding calling on main (or non-main) thread? Only that it's thread-safe?

Comment: @Peter Yeah, apple doesn't detail it or make it bold enough IMO, and there are some exceptions that they make, but they really don't properly detail what is and what is not ok. So, you just have to stay safe by assuming it is not because threading issues and version specific issues are no fun if you try to fight the system. This is also the case for OS X (which is improving slowly in this regard). The general assumption is that it's not safe unless explicitly documented. Also: Reference added to answer.

Comment: "Thread-safe" means different things to different people, and even means different things within Apple documentation.  In my experience, unless the docs explicitly state otherwise, if a class starts with UI (i.e. everything in UIKit), you should consider it to be main-thread only. More details here: http://tinyurl.com/co6353b

Answer (score 0):

Might as well call them on the main thread just to be sure.